# Is there a way to send message from a queue to a specific instance via instance id

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to send a message to a specific ec2 instance. If I have 3 machines up and running I want the message will be served only to the no-2 instance.

Want to serve the message only to the specific instance?
I have the instance-id for the machine but don't know how can we do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "message"? What do you mean by "served"? Are you referring to an HTTP request, or a message in an Amazon SQS queue? Please note that Amazon SQS Queues do not 'send' messages. Rather, software needs to make an API request to the queue to request messages. See: [Basic Amazon SQS architecture - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html)

Comment: Yes i have the software runs on ec2 to entertain the messages from the sqs but i want to send the specific message to a specific ec2 instance

Comment: It is not possible to 'send' messages using Amazon SQS. You could create 3 queues (one per instance) and then have code running on each instance check its SQS queue to see if there are any messages available to process. This is a 'pull' model rather than a 'push' model.

Comment: messages means the queue message sent to process. 
served means where the message or payload will be catered

Comment: SQS doesn't support message filtering.  The consumers of an SQS Queue share mesages.  You should look at SNS.  It supports message filtering and can deliver to queues based on filter, so then you'd have one instance per queue.  Or you could use a different mechanism like sns -> https

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.